# speed php load time up

Tags: php, foreach

i have the following php code:

```
// Add the unsubscribers to an array
$unsubs = array();
foreach($unsubscribers->response->Results as $entry2) {
    $unsubs[] = $entry2->EmailAddress;
}

// Loop through the subscribers
foreach($result->response->Results as $entry) { 

    echo '<tr class="'. $entry->EmailAddress.'">';      
    echo '<td>'. $entry->EmailAddress.'</td>';
    echo '<td></td><td>';

    // If the subscriber is in our unsubscriber array, output the email again
    if(in_array($entry->EmailAddress, $unsubs)) { 
        echo $entry->EmailAddress;
    }

    echo '</td><td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Where the empty `<td></td>` are located i would like to place the following:

```
$getlists = new CS_REST_Campaigns($_POST['campaign_id'], $auth);
$getlistsresult = $wrap->get_lists_and_segments();
    foreach($getlistsresult->response->Lists as $list) {
        //echo $list->ListID;
    } 

$wrapcount = new CS_REST_Subscribers($list->ListID, $auth);
$resultcount = $wrapcount->get_history($entry->EmailAddress);   


    foreach($resultcount->response as $entrycount) { 

        $counts = array();

foreach($entrycount->Actions as $actions) {
    if(!isset($counts[$actions->Event])) {
        $counts[$actions->Event] = 0;
    }
    ++$counts[$actions->Event];
}


    echo '<td>';
    if ($counts['Click']){echo $counts['Click'];} 
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    if ($counts['Bounce']){echo 'Yes';}
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    if ($counts['Open']){echo $counts['Open'];} 
    echo '</td>';

    }
```

This works to a degree, but the load time of the page is dramatically increased. I think to be honest my code will need tidying up. Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

Comment: The bottleneck is within `CS_REST_Campaigns::get_lists_and_segments()` and/or `CS_REST_Subscribers::get_history()` - without knowing what they do and how they do it there's no way to help you speed it up. You should look at a profiler such as http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: thanks for the link. Those files are straight from a php wrapper provided by campaign monitor. I havent changed those in anyway, so they shouldn't be causing any problems.

Comment: It looks like those are making requests to an external API, I would be very surprised if that is not the cause of your slowdown. You are waiting for at least 2 other HTTP requests to fully process before you can continue to process the one you are currently handling. The loops should consume no more than a few milliseconds, and that would be if they are dealing with a *lot* of data, it's most likely a lot less.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much I can see that is blatantly unoptimized in your code, there are functions calls that I don't know about, from your CS_REST classes, but we don't know what these functions do or if they can be slow or optimized.

With this information, the only thing I can see that might help you is using the [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) class. This will be notably useful if you have a lot of entries in your arrays and do a lot of operations on them. Basically, they are similar to real arrays, in the way that their index is always an integer and they have a fixed size, which in turn makes them faster to use.